# How can I pass a pointer to array of pointers to structs from python

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes

I am using ctypes in Python and I need to pass a pointer to an array of pointers to structs to some C function.
This is struct:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float radius;
} Sphere;
```

And I have function with the following prototype:

```
void render(Sphere** spheres);
```

In Python I declared a class for the Sphere struct and I need to set argtypes to the `render` function:

```
lib_render = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('librender.so')

class Sphere(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_float),
                ('y', ctypes.c_float),
                ('z', ctypes.c_float),
                ('radius', ctypes.c_float)]

render = lib_render.render
render.argtypes = [<cannot find out what needs to be here>]

spheres = numpy.array([Sphere(1, 2.8, 3, 0.5),
                       Sphere(4.2, 2, 1, 3.2)])
render(spheres)
```

How to pass that array correctly?

Comment: I have not tested this, but I'd assume it would be `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(Sphere))`

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work. It can't convert numpy array to `LP_LP_Sphere` automatically and if I'm passing to the function `spheres.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(POINTER(Sphere)))` the function receives unknown garbage, all different for each time.

Comment: Have you looked into `numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer`?

Comment: Yes, once I used it for passing pointer to an array of integers or some other C types this way: `np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype = np.int32, ndim = 1, flags = 'C_CONTIGUOUS')`
But I had no idea how to apply this for array of pointers to structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use numpy much, but the follow works without it.  I am assuming if you are passing a pointer to pointers that the pointer list must be null-terminated.

```
from ctypes import *

class Sphere(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c_float),
                ('y', c_float),
                ('z', c_float),
                ('radius', c_float)]

dll = CDLL('test')
dll.render.argtypes = POINTER(POINTER(Sphere)),
dll.render.restype = None

# Create a couple of objects
a = Sphere(1,2,3,4)
b = Sphere(5,6,7,8)

# build a list of pointers, null-terminated.
c = (POINTER(Sphere) * 3)(pointer(a),pointer(b),None)
dll.render(c)
```

Test DLL:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Sphere {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float radius;
} Sphere;

__declspec(dllexport) void render(Sphere** spheres)
{
    for(;*spheres;++spheres)
        printf("%f %f %f %f\n",(*spheres)->x,(*spheres)->y,(*spheres)->z,(*spheres)->radius);
}
```

Output:

```
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000
5.000000 6.000000 7.000000 8.000000
```

With `numpy`, using `void render(Sphere* spheres, size_t len)`, this works.  Maybe someone more familiar with numpy can comment if `Sphere**` can be supported.

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

class Sphere(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c_float),
                ('y', c_float),
                ('z', c_float),
                ('radius', c_float)]

dll = CDLL('test')
dll.render.argtypes = POINTER(Sphere),c_size_t
dll.render.restype = None

a = Sphere(1,2,3,4)
b = Sphere(5,6,7,8)
# c = (Sphere * 2)(a,b)
# dll.render(c,len(c))
d = np.array([a,b])
dll.render(d.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(Sphere)),len(d))
```

Comment: Nice approach. I didn't know you can just multiply pointer by a number and get array of pointers. I think I even don't need a numpy array.